# Arranging $100$ balls.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $100$ balls numbered $n_{1}, n_{2}, n_{3}\cdots \cdots n_{100}$ .
>    They are arranged in all possible ways . How many arrangements 
>   would be there in which $n_{28}$ ball will always be before $n_{29}$ ball 
>   and the two of them will be adjacent to each other ?

$a.)\ \dfrac{99!}{2!} \\
b.)\ 99!2! \\
\color{green}{c.)\ 99! }\\
d.)\ \text{none of these } \\$

I arranged $\{\cdots \cdots n_{28},n_{29}\}$

Total ways $(100-2)!=98!$.

But

Answer given in book is $99!$.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: You can glue these two balls together, and then you're just arranging 99 objects in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let's rephrase the question:

- There are $27$ balls numbered $n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},\dots,n_{27}$
- There are $71$ balls numbered $n_{30},n_{31},n_{32},\dots,n_{100}$
- There is $1$ ball numbered $n_{2829}$

> Altogether, there are $27+71+1$ balls. How many arrangements are there?

Answer (score 3):

Let suppose that $n_{28}$ is first and $n_{29}$ is second.  Then there are $98!$ ways to arrange the other balls.  Now, $n_{28}$ can be placed in any of the positions from $1$ to $99$.  So the total number of possibilites is $99\cdot 98!=99!$.

Answer (score 1):

We can imagine $n_{28}-n_{29}$ glued together as one object. Then it is like we have 99 balls and the total permutations are $99!$